# using COUNTIF with blank value criteria with variable ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have sort of a bizarre issue here attempting to use `COUNTIF`.

pretend for a moment this is the sheet in question:

```
A        B
John     Doe
John     Smith
John
```

The last value there (B3) is an empty field.

The intended `COUNTIF` formula should count the number of empty values in the `B` column only IF John is present in the A column.

The only way I have been able to do this successfully is explicitly specifying the range to be counted (`B1:B3`), but this formula is going to be doing this on multiple sheets that do not all have the same number of rows, therefore, I cannot use `COUNTBLANK` because it is returning staggeringly high results if I simply name the `B` column a name and specify the name as the range.

---

EDIT:

So apparently countif cannot be used for that? A workaround I have found is using `SUMPRODUCT`. Is this the best way to go about doing this?

`=SUMPRODUCT((September!K1:K16000="John")*(September!L1:L16000=""))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS` for multiple criteria. For instance, you can use:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"John",B:B,"")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I kept reading in various articles that there is no such thing as a null/blank value in Excel and it was driving me nuts..

Comment: @Grace Glad to help ^^

Comment: This doesn't appear to work if the criteria is coming from a blank cell, blank doesn't appear to match blank. E.g. `=COUNTIFS(A:A, D1, B:B, E1)` doesn't work. The workaround is to replace blank with "", i.e. `=COUNTIFS(A:A, IF(ISBLANK(D1), "", D1), B:B, IF(ISBLANK(E1), "", E1))`

Comment: Another workaround can be to count all answers with `"*"` and then subtract that from the total without that particular criteria. E.g. `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"John") - COUNTIFS(A:A,"John",B:B,"*")`

Comment: @Tom yes, the downside is that this formula is potentially twice as slow because you are invoking countif twice (well, one countif and one countifs). For large sets of data, it can be a long wait time.

Answer (score 2):

Use `=SUM(IF(A1:A3="John",1,0)*IF(ISBLANK(B1:B3),1,0))`

This is an array formula: use Ctrl + Shift + Return once you've finished editing rather than just Return.

The trick is to use a multiplication as a replacement to an AND function as AND fails if you mix array string comparisions with ISBLANK.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
=COUNTBLANK(B2:B100000)-COUNTBLANK(A2:A100000)
```

It calcaulates the diference between the empty cells in column B and the empty cells in column A.