# Excel formula – Count if total equals string AND adjacent row empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm a total Excel beginner and would like to do the following:

Go through my A1:A3000, and return a count if it reads "6-Month Plan".

=COUNTIF(A1:A3000, "=6-Month Plan")

The above works as I'd like it to. But I want to go a step further and make it so that if A1 equals 6-Month Plan, I also want it to check to see if B1 is an empty string or not – If it is empty, count should return true.

```
----------------------------
|   |       A       |   B  |
----------------------------
| 1 |  6-Month Plan |  foo |
| 2 |  6-Month Plan |  bar |
| 3 |  3-Month Plan |      |
| 4 |  3-Month Plan |  baz |
| 5 |  6-Month Plan |      |
```

The above should only return "1" – 3 6-Month plans were found, but only one was adjacent to an empty B string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for COUNTIFS

=COUNTIFS(A1:A3000, "6-Month Plan", B1:B3000, "")

Free from:
[using COUNTIF with blank value criteria with variable ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858950/using-countif-with-blank-value-criteria-with-variable-ranges)

Answer (score 1):

This works in my test

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"6-Month Plan",B:B,"")
```